# Как сделать первый слайд активным в цикле?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, html5, bootstrap

У меня есть слайдер на 4 бутстрапе:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 is-simple">
                                <img class="img-fluid main-slider-img" src="<?php echo first_post_image($post_id_68) ?>" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php echo $link_68 ?>">
                            <div class="col-6" align="center">
                                <p class="is-orange-header margin-top-25"><?php echo $title_68; ?></p>
                                <span class="slider-text"><?php echo $excerpt_68; ?></span><br />
                                <a class="left-arrow" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-left main-slider-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                                <span class=" main-slider-arrow"> 1 / 2</span>
                                <a class="right-arrow" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right main-slider-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 is-simple">
                                <img class="img-fluid main-slider-img" src="<?php echo first_post_image($post_id_73) ?>" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php echo $link_73 ?>">
                            <div class="col-6" align="center">
                                <p class="is-orange-header margin-top-25"><?php echo $title_73; ?></p>
                                <span class="slider-text"><?php echo $excerpt_73; ?></span><br />
                                <a class="left-arrow" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-left main-slider-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                                <span class=" main-slider-arrow"> 2 / 2</span>
                                <a class="right-arrow" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right main-slider-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Сейчас записи из базы забираютсяв ручную, но я хочу переделать это в цикл, я получаю всю нужную мне инфу, я так понимаю что мне нужно будет запихнуть вот этот код слайда в цикл

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6 is-simple">
                            <img class="img-fluid main-slider-img" src="<?php echo first_post_image($post_id_68) ?>" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <a href="<?php echo $link_68 ?>">
                        <div class="col-6" align="center">
                            <p class="is-orange-header margin-top-25"><?php echo $title_68; ?></p>
                            <span class="slider-text"><?php echo $excerpt_68; ?></span><br />
                            <a class="left-arrow" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left main-slider-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class=" main-slider-arrow"> 1 / 2</span>
                            <a class="right-arrow" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="fa fa-chevron-right main-slider-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Но вопрос в том,что у первого слайда class="active", а как я понимаю, цикл while будет дублировать слайды, как сделать так что бы active добавился первому элементу, ну или убирать его у всех остальных?

[image]

Comment: Если вы собираетесь выводить всё это средствами php, то можете до цикла задать значение переменной `<?php $slide_class='active'; ?>`. В цикле вывод делаете так `<div class="carousel-item <?= $slide_class; ?>">`, а потом простое переназначаете переменную `<?php $slide_class = ''; ?>`

Comment: @Pyramidhead Переназначить переменную в теле цикла?

Comment: Но если хотите всё сделать средствами js (так как тега php в вопросе нет), то просто по событию `document.ready` назначайте первому дочернему элементу класс `active` таким образом `jQuery( ".carousel-inner .carousel-item:first-child" ).addClass('active');`

Comment: Да, в теле цикла. Сначала вывод, а потом установка нового значения.

Comment: @Pyramidhead добавил картинку как я сделал в конец вопроса, не помогло(

Comment: Поместите код в виде кода

Comment: Будьте внимательнее. Я написал, что `<?php $slide_class='active'; ?>` нужно вынести перед циклом. То есть перед `while`.